# Finding the all data of two tables with Conditional Join in a resultset

Tags: mysql

I want to find the results in one query

```
packages table

id | name   |

1    Silver 

2    Gold

3   Platinum

user_package table

uid| pid| is_active

1     1    1
```

Now I need fo find the all packages details with user_package ,i.e here user 1 has taken package 1

```
uid|pid|is_active|name

 1  1        1    Silver
null 2      null   Gold
null 3      null  Platinum
```

I used left join but I am getting only one result.

```
select user_package.* , packages.name 
from packages 
left join user_package on user_package.pid = packages.id 
where user_package.uid=1;
```

But I am getting only one result set. Thanks in advance for your feedback , suggestion and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your where clause turns your left join into inner join, so you will get data from `packages` table where related data exists in `user_package`, If you need all package details whether they have associated records in `user_package` or not then move your where criteria in `on` clause as additional criteria to join rows from `user_package`

```
select u.*,
p.name 
from packages p
left join user_package u on u.pid = p.id 
and u.uid=1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f21c3b/2)

Comment: I am getting all user_packages data which is available in user_packages. i.e  if there is multiple entries of another user with different package id  in user_packages table but  I need only filed of that particular user id other should be null, Please help me out for this point

Comment: @ak001 can you ask a new question for this ?

Answer (score 0):

it is only one result because you specify `on user_package.pid = packages.id` and in the table `user_package` there is only one record.

you can add dummy record in table `user_package` as you needed